# Issues with Nvidia graphics driver and CUDA after apt-get upgrade

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda

I previously installed CUDA 7.5 on Ubuntu 14.04 using the "deb (network)" install from Nvidia. It has worked for a few months, until I ran `sudo apt-get upgrade` today. After doing this, I encountered the following

```
$ nvidia-smi
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:809 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='nvidia_352'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_352': Function not implemented
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Running `sudo nvidia-smi` is no different.
I am unable to login in GUI mode (it just goes back to the login screen after I enter my password), but I can access the terminal.

*I have been able to restore graphical functionality, however I am having difficulty re-installing CUDA after that. Can you please help me?*

### Restoring graphics

I have found that I can get the graphics to work again by doing

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and then editing `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list` to remove all lines, then doing

```
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
```

and rebooting the system. After this, `nvidia-smi` is working again. However, I still need to re-install CUDA.

### Trying to re-install CUDA

I tried restoring the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list` and then doing `sudo apt-get install cuda`.
I noticed this error message:

```
Loading new nvidia-352-352.93 DKMS files...
Building only for 3.13.0-68-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.13.0-68-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-352.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.13.0-68-generic (x86_64)
```

After doing this, the system is returned to its behaviour at the start.
For example, `nvidia-smi` prints the error message above, and after building and running `deviceQuery` I get a similar error:

```
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:809 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='nvidia_352'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_352': Function not implemented
cudaGetDeviceCount returned 38
-> no CUDA-capable device is detected
Result = FAIL
```

I seem to recall that when I first installed CUDA, it would only work if I did it without updating the `nvidia-352` package from the Nvidia repositories.
However, now I don't seem to have the option of doing that, because when I run `sudo apt-get install cuda` it automatically upgrades the `nvidia-352` package:

```
Unpacking nvidia-352 (352.93-0ubuntu1) over (352.63-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
```

If I try to set the versions explicitly, I get

```
$ sudo apt-get install cuda-drivers nvidia-352=352.63-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 nvidia-352-dev=352.63-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 cuda-drivers : Depends: nvidia-352 (>= 352.93) but 352.63-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-352-dev (>= 352.93) but 352.63-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

In fact, if I try to use version `352.63-0ubuntu1` instead of `352.63-0ubuntu0.14.04.1` by doing

```
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-352=352.63-0ubuntu1
```

then this is enough to break the graphical login and cause `nvidia-smi` to display the error message above.

### Diagnostics

```
$ lspci | grep -i vga
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM200 [GeForce GTX TITAN X] (rev a1)

$ dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia
ii  bbswitch-dkms                                         0.7-2ubuntu1                                        amd64        Interface for toggling the power on nVidia Optimus video cards
ii  libcuda1-352                                          352.93-0ubuntu1                                     amd64        NVIDIA CUDA runtime library
ii  nvidia-352                                            352.93-0ubuntu1                                     amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 352.93
ii  nvidia-352-dev                                        352.93-0ubuntu1                                     amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver development files
ii  nvidia-352-uvm                                        352.93-0ubuntu1                                     amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-352
ii  nvidia-modprobe                                       352.93-0ubuntu1                                     amd64        Load the NVIDIA kernel driver and create device files
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-352                                 352.93-0ubuntu1                                     amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-prime                                          0.6.2                                               amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                                       352.93-0ubuntu1                                     amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A friend was able to solve it for me!

The solution that he showed me was to (after removing all nvidia packages as before)

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-364
```

then download the .run CUDA installer (for me it was cuda_7.5.18_linux.run) from Nvidia and be careful to choose "no" when asked whether you want to install the driver that is packaged with CUDA.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem. Was able to solve this by installing the recommended version of nvidia driver.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-drivers-common

sudo ubuntu-drivers devices

sudo apt-get install <recommended version>
```

Comment: I had to issue the command "sudo modprobe nvidia" after the above commands then every thing was working

Comment: @MARK I'm getting error by modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_396': Required key not available. Any tips?