# Getting CUDA 8.0 to work on Ubuntu 16.04, NVIDIA driver issue

Tags: 16.04, cuda, nvidia-geforce

I've spent a couple of days on this and am at my wit's end as to how to move forward.

I have an ASUS Zenbook UX303UB with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 Dual boot. It has an NVIDIA GeForce 940M dedicated GPU with 2GB memory. I use Ubuntu primarily for programming. I want to play around with some deep learning tools like tensorflow and theano, for which I first need CUDA to work. Only CUDA 8.0rc appears to work with Ubuntu 16.04 officially.

First, I went to the NVIDIA website and downloaded the CUDA 8.0 runfile. I followed their instructions to install and did so in TTY1, including blacklisting noveau and adding

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

to the end of the .bashrc file.

When I try the test example that NVIDIA provides,

```
$ cd NVIDIA_CUDA-8.0_Samples/5_Simulations/nbody
$ make
```

my output is:

```
>>> WARNING - libGLU.so not found, refer to CUDA Getting Started Guide for how to find and install them. <<<
>>> WARNING - gl.h not found, refer to CUDA Getting Started Guide for how to find and install them. <<<
>>> WARNING - glu.h not found, refer to CUDA Getting Started Guide for how to find and install them. <<<
[@] /usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++ -I../../common/inc -m64 -ftz=true -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=compute_60 -o bodysystemcuda.o -c bodysystemcuda.cu
[@] /usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++ -I../../common/inc -m64 -ftz=true -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=compute_60 -o nbody.o -c nbody.cpp
[@] /usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++ -I../../common/inc -m64 -ftz=true -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=compute_60 -o render_particles.o -c render_particles.cpp
[@] /usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++ -m64 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=compute_60 -o nbody bodysystemcuda.o nbody.o render_particles.o -L/usr/lib/nvidia-361 -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lglut
[@] mkdir -p ../../bin/x86_64/linux/release
[@] cp nbody ../../bin/x86_64/linux/release
```

when I then do

```
$ ./nbody -benchmark -numbodies=256000 -device=0
```

I get the message

```
bash: ./nbody: No such file or directory
```

In the diagnosis process, I realized 2 things:

1) `nvidia-smi` doesn't seem to work (`nvidia-smi: command not found`)

2) When I do `cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version` I get `cat: /proc/driver/nvidia/version: No such file or directory`

I then decided perhaps there is some trouble with the NVIDIA driver. So I followed the instructions on
[Issues with Nvidia graphics driver and CUDA after apt-get upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784392/issues-with-nvidia-graphics-driver-and-cuda-after-apt-get-upgrade)

Basically, to purge all nvidia drivers, turn off lightdm and enter runlevel3, and install the NVIDIA driver runfile from NVIDIA's website.

However, there is an installation error and it aborts.

I then reboot and purge all nvidia drivers and do a `sudo apt-get install nvidia-367`

I'm back to square one now. Additional diagnostic information as follows:

```
$ sudo nvidia-modprobe
sudo: nvidia-modprobe: command not found

$ uname -r
4.4.0-36-generic

$ dpkg -l | grep ii | grep -i linux-headers
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-31                      4.4.0-31.50                                                 all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.4.0
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic              4.4.0-31.50                                                 amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-34                      4.4.0-34.53                                                 all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.4.0
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-34-generic              4.4.0-34.53                                                 amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-36                      4.4.0-36.55                                                 all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.4.0
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-36-generic              4.4.0-36.55                                                 amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic                       4.4.0.36.38                                                 amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers

$ dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia
ii  bbswitch-dkms                               0.8-3ubuntu1                                                amd64        Interface for toggling the power on NVIDIA Optimus video cards
ii  libcuda1-367                                367.44-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1                                  amd64        NVIDIA CUDA runtime library
ii  nvidia-367                                  367.44-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1                                  amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 367.44
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-367                       367.44-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1                                  amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-prime                                0.8.2                                                       amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                             370.23-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1                                  amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver

$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_May__4_21:01:56_CDT_2016
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.26
```

Any help would be much appreciated, as I have come very close to breaking ubuntu a bunch of times!!

Comment: This blog may help: https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/Install-Ubuntu-16-04-or-14-04-and-CUDA-8-and-7-5-for-NVIDIA-Pascal-GPU-825/ *I am still reviewing, and don't agree with all of the methods described.* Will post answer here, when I have had time test this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by following this tutorial: http://kislayabhi.github.io/Installing_CUDA_with_Ubuntu/

Follow it loosely, i.e. download and install the lastest driver from nvidia's website instead of downloading and installing nvidia-367 which the tutorial recommends.

Comment: Please add the important points from the post and add your modifications so in case the link changes we will have a working copy.