# After installing correct NVIDIA driver, nvidia-smi still can't find it. (Ubuntu 18.4)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, cuda

I'm trying to set up my system for CUDA by installing the lastest NVIDIA drivers. I've already installed the drivers, but still get an error when running `nvidia-smi`

```
~ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

After getting this message, I followed a few various tutorials, namely this one: [Issues with Nvidia graphics driver and CUDA after apt-get upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784392/issues-with-nvidia-graphics-driver-and-cuda-after-apt-get-upgrade)\

But when I try and purge the old drivers, I get an error:

```
~ sudo apt-get purge nvidia*                  
zsh: no matches found: nvidia* (**EDIT**: THIS HAS BEEN FIXED, I CAN NOW PURGE, but that didn't help)
```

Yet, I can't just install the most recent drivers, because they are already installed.

```
~ sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-396
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nvidia-driver-396 is already the newest version (396.54-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libnvidia-common-390 libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-server0:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I think my best bet at this point is still to delete and reinstall the driver, but I'm not sure how to do that. And I don't know why the driver isn't being used.

**Additional Notes:**

```
 lsmod | grep nvidia
 dmesg | grep NVRM
```

also return nothing.

Why is the driver still not registered? Any help is appreciated.

**Edit** 
I was able to purge the existing nvidia and try again, but it's still not working.

It seems that the problem might be that nouveau isn't disabled properly.

When I check which driver is being used:

```
➜  Documents sudo lshw -class video | grep driver=
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
```

So it's still there. I had used this site https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-nouveau-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux
to guide me through disabling it. Running the following command gives the expected result:

```
➜  Documents cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

And it still doesn't work. Thoughts?

Comment: Try quoting your wildcard filenames in the purge, or using the explicit pacakge names.  Anything blacklisting nvidia in /etc/modprobe.d/...?

Comment: @ubfan1 It looks like something is blacklisting 'nvidiafb' could that be the culprit? Also thanks for the purge tip. Trying it now.

Comment: I have nvidiafb blacklisted too, so I guess that's not a problem. How did you install the Nvidia drivers the first time?  I do it from the Software and Updates app from the Additional drivers tab.  Works for me, then get CUDA, but I'm limited by hardware to CUDA 8.x.

Comment: I might have found the problem (see first edit). Still don't know the solution.

Comment: The standard Nvidia driver install from the Additional Drivers tab should include a file, /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf, in package nvidia-kernel-common-390 (the last number may vary), which contains the blacklist of nouveau and of lbm-nouveau, as well as aliases to "off' for both.

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04, CUDA now installs as `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit`.  You have the proper NVIDIA driver installation step.  However, you haven't stated what video card you have.  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1068626/edit) your question and add the output of `inxi -G` that should show what video card you have.

Comment: Or, if `inxi -G` returns nothing, try running `lspci | grep -i vga` and add that to your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you purged nvidia drivers then reinstalled them you need to `prime-select` back-and-forth to intel then back to nvidia:

`prime-select intel`

`prime-select nvidia`

After this `nvidia-smi` should succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, It might be hard, where if I got it right nvidia is supporting officially only 16.04 & 17.10 for CUDA. So it could need some efforts to get it working with 18.04, have you checked nvidia forums any guidance for it.

Comment: I haven't yet. I'll see what I can find there. Thanks

Comment: I've checked all over and tried two methods: https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-nvidia-driver-ubuntu-18-04 and https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux I think I found the potential problem. (see edit)